# Getting Corelation id in logs

Tags: java, s4sdk

I have created an application of SAP Springboot archetype and published it to SAP Cloud foundry and can see the corelation id being generated in the Kibana Logs.

But I was not able to retrieve the CorelationId. I wanted this generated corelation id to be passed from the publisher to consumer through RabbitMQ.

I have tried a lot but I couldn't succeed. Please let me know how to get this Id?

Comment: Which correlation Ids are you referring to?

Comment: I am doing an asynchronous call between 2 services(Using SAP Springboot archetype scp-cf-spring) using RabbitMq and we are using the application logger services for logging.I could see the generated correlation id in the Kibana Logs for this application. The same, I wanted to get in my Application code. Please suggest how to get the same.

Comment: Hi Arun, if you're satisfied with Sander's answer, please mark it as 'accepted' so other people looking for help can see it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is not possible given that the ID is generated by SAP Cloud Platform when writing the log file. The SDK offers the `ErrorResponseBuilder` class to generate a reference ID when an exception is thrown in the application to have a reference ID both on the API level (error response) and in the log file. This aims to avoid the exposure of internal application information to the API. But I think this is not exactly what you are aiming for, so you may have to generate an identifier by yourself and bring it to the log.